# Problemas en boton de paginación en Laravel 8 con CoreUI

Tags: css, laravel, bootstrap-4, laravel-blade

Cordial saludo comunidad

Les explico mi problema. Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Laravel 8 usando una plantilla de CoreUI que usa Bootstrap 4.0. Tengo una consulta a la base de datos donde estoy paginando los resultados de a dos item de la siguiente manera

```
 public function index(Request $request)
    {
        if($request){
            $sql = trim($request->get('buscarTexto'));
            $categorias = DB::table('categorias')->where('nombre','LIKE','%'.$sql.'%')->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(2);
            return view('categoria.index',["categorias" => $categorias, "buscarTexto" => $sql]);
            //return $categorias;

        }
    }
```

Al momento de devolver el resultado, no se porque motivo el botón de la paginación sale inmenso cuando en los ejemplos que veo siempre sale bien. No se si el problema es de laravel 8 o la versión de Bootstrap (ya la cambié para 4.5 y nada)

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Agradezco la colaboración y la ayuda que me puedan brindar desde su experiencia. Muchas gracias

Comment: Has revisado el DevTools? Qué información del frontend te muestra Bootstrap, por ejemplo? Las clases o propiedades que utiliza la paginación. A lo mejor allí te da una idea de los archivos a los que hacen referencia los estilos que se están aplicando.

Comment: @JheymanMejia en realidad no entiendo mucho tu pregunta, estuve averiguando y he encontrado que el paginator usa Tailwind CSS y que hay que agregar una linea de codigo para que el paginador use bootstrap pero no explican muy bien como hacerlo

Comment: Cuando estás sobre la página, puedes presionar `F12` o `Control + Shift + I` para que abra la ventana de DevTools (o Inspeccionar Elemento) allí con el cursor seleccionas el ícono de la paginación y ves las propiedades que le afectan (su tamaño y demás) así mismo vas a ver el archivo donde están dichas propiedades, y modificarlo si es necesario.

Comment: Tengo el mismo probrema, no se como solucionarlo

Answer (score 6):

Es debido a que Laravel usa la paginación Tailwind para cambiar esto dirígete a:

```
App\Providers\AppServiceProvider
```

Y agrega el siguiente USE

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;
```

Y dentro de la parte de la funcion boot

```
Paginator::useBootstrap();
```

Te dejo una vista general y el link a la documentación de Laravel donde soluciona esto.

```
use Illuminate\Pagination\Paginator;

/**
 * Bootstrap any application services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    Paginator::useBootstrap();
}
```

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/pagination#using-bootstrap

Answer (score 0):

el problema es que por defecto la vista que trae laravel para paginar utiliza el Tailwind CSS y debes cambiarlo a boosstrap, para esto utiliza el comando

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=laravel-pagination
```

Y luego puedes personalizar las vistas generadas en **`resources/views/vendor/pagination/`** o cambiar la vista por defecto a una que prefieras de bootstrap  en tu vista seria asi:

```
{{$categorias->links('vendor.pagination.bootstrap-4)}}
```

Hay otra forma que es cambiar el **`app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php`**
aqui te dejo el link donde lo [explican todo](https://styde.net/tip-de-optimizacion-con-eloquent-4-utiliza-paginacion/)